# making function that checks if vector exists in matrix faster

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have the following function (funtest) to test if a specific vector exists in a matrix. The vector will always be length 2 and the matrix will always have two columns. The function works fine, I would just like to make it faster (ideally much faster), because my matrices can have hundreds to thousands of rows.

```
x = c(1,2)

set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(sample(c(1,-2,3,4), 500*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=2)

funtest(m,x)
[1] TRUE
```

This is how fast it currently is

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funtest(m, x), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
 funtest(m, x) 1.501247 1.536157 1.674668 1.567826 1.708293 2.900046
 neval
   100
```

This is the function

```
funtest = function(m, x) {
    out = any(apply(m,1,function(n,x) all(n==x),x=x))
    return(out)
}
```

Comment: I'm not an R user per se, but this looks like a highly vectorized expression, so that you are doing checks without branching. This is in general easier to parallelize on the processor but sometimes is just slower than a more domain-driven approach. Maybe it would be better to collect all row-indices first, where the first element is equal the given value. Then only check on the already filtered second column (only comparing with the indexes positive from step 1; like short-circuiting in boolean evaluations). The speedup should be limited by a factor of ~2 though.

Comment: You should definitely try the approach by Zheyuan Li first, as it has more speedup potential and it may feel more natural in a vectorized language. (But sadly it all boils down to R's internals; what does apply do compared to the mentioned alternative). Of course data-statistics might play a role too with branching-based approaches.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe some kind of hash alternative to search in constant time?

Comment: @user3067923 I'm pretty sure hashing-based approaches lose all the time because of the big constants (complexity-wise). This is a linear-complexity operation, so i won't tackle it that way. (To make it more clear: you need to look at all rows, that's a lower bound; and direct comparison will alway be faster than hashing; at least if you are hashing all columns -> there might be a good probabilistic trade-off approach with many columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
paste(x[1], x[2], sep='&') %in% paste(m[,1], m[,2], sep='&')
```

This should be super efficient! It is based on matching. As soon as the first match is found, no further search will be done!

However I am sure this is not the fastest. The optimal solution is to write this operation in C code with a single while loop. But, the potential speedup factor should be no more than 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Rcpp (specifically Rcpp Armadillo) approach. Benchmarks are given at the end:

```
# Import the relevant packages (All for compiling the C++ code inline)
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(inline)

# We need to include these namespaces in the C++ code 
includes <- '
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
'

# This is the main C++ function 
# We cast 'm' as an Armadillo matrix 'm1' and compute the number of rows 'numRows'
# We cast 'x' as a row vector 'x1'
# We then loop through the rows of the matrix 
# As soon as we find a matching row (anyEqual = TRUE), we stop and return TRUE
# If no matching row is found, then anyEqual = FALSE and we return FALSE
# Note: Within the for loop, we do an elementwise comparison of a row of m1 to x1
# If the row is equal to x1, then the sum of the elementwise comparision should equal the number of elements of x1
src <- '
mat m1 = as<mat>(m); 
int numRows = m1.n_rows;
rowvec x1 = as<rowvec>(x);
bool anyEqual = FALSE;
for (int i = 0; i < numRows & !anyEqual; i++){
    anyEqual = (sum(m1.row(i) == x1) == x1.size());
}
return(wrap(anyEqual));
'

# Here, we compile the function above
# Do this once (in a given R session) and use it as many times as desired
rcppFn <- cxxfunction(signature(m="numeric", x="numeric"), src, plugin='RcppArmadillo', includes)
```

Benchmarks are here: (Edit: I've added a benchmark for @zheyuan-li very simple solution below too; it is called pasteFn)

```
# Your function is called funtest
# Rcpp function is rcppFn
# Zheyuan's solution is pasteFn
microbenchmark(funtest(m, x), rcppFn(m, x), pasteFn(m, x), times=100, unit = "ms")
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 funtest(m, x) 1.127903 1.1984755 1.30559130 1.2514455 1.3431040 2.641258   100
  rcppFn(m, x) 0.005420 0.0061355 0.00879676 0.0073660 0.0084130 0.030305   100
 pasteFn(m, x) 0.741269 0.7610905 0.79174042 0.7752145 0.8228895 0.894389   100
```

Edit: If you would like to use a matrix 'x' instead, the following source code should work

```
src <- '
mat m1 = as<mat>(m); 
int numRows = m1.n_rows;
mat x1 = as<mat>(x);
vec anyEqual = zeros<vec>(x1.n_rows);
for (int j = 0; j < x1.n_rows; j++){
for (int i = 0; i < numRows & !anyEqual(j); i++){
anyEqual(j) = (sum(m1.row(i) == x1.row(j)) == x1.n_cols);
}
}
return(wrap(anyEqual));
'
```

Here, I am just checking for each row of x, whether it exists in m. Very similar to the original code except that have one extra for loop. It would return 1 or 0 depending on if there's a match (not experienced enough with RcppArmadillo to create a vector of bools).

Comment: can this be made to accept x being a matrix instead of a vector to search by? say `x = matrix(data = c(1,2,-3,5,4,10), ncol=2)` instead of `x= c(1,2)`

Answer (score 3):

`base::bitwXor()` will produce `0` for a match between two integers.

**Note:** `bitwXor()` works for integers only

**EDIT** : Added comparison with `0` from `bitwXor` and added data.table solution

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(sample(c(1,-2,3,4), 500*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=2)

fun1 <- function(m,x) {any(apply(m,1,function(n,x) all(n==x),x=x))}
fun2 <- function(m,x) {paste(x[1], x[2], sep='&') %in% paste(m[,1], m[,2], sep='&')}
fun3 <- function(m,x) {any((bitwXor(m[,1], x[1]) == 0) & (bitwXor(m[,2], x[2]) == 0))}
fun4 <- function(m,x) {setDT(m)[X1 == x[1] & X2 == x[2], .N > 0]}

x <-  c(1,2)

microbenchmark(fun1(m,x),     # @user3067923
               fun2(m,x),     # @Zheyuan Li
               rcppFn(m, x),  # @jav
               fun3(m,x),
               times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#         expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
#   fun1(m, x) 1802.483 1920.007 2156.93459 1995.865 2094.820 9915.013  1000
#   fun2(m, x) 1540.716 1602.534 1674.39556 1641.256 1702.848 2832.344  1000
# rcppFn(m, x)   14.040   16.305   23.43586   21.739   29.439   95.107  1000
#   fun3(m, x)   70.650   76.992   86.36290   82.879   88.766  314.303  1000
```

**Data.Table solution:**

```
library(data.table)
m <- data.frame(m)
microbenchmark(fun4(m,x), times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min       lq     mean median      uq      max neval
# fun4(m, x) 836.026 887.6555 985.8596 920.49 968.269 9025.546  1000
```